# create peerAdminCard in composer-admin api?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I want to create peerAdmin@***.card via node. I only find `exportCard，importCard etc.` api in adminConnection.
How can I create a peerAdmin card or other card using composer-admin api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer to examples (to create cards using the JS APIs) here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#cardapis (there are links to source files eg. from item 2 onwards)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using composer CLI then execute the following command to perform operation on card:

**To Creates a business network card from a connection profile**

```
composer card create
```

**To Delete a business network card which you have imported locally**

```
composer card delete
```

example : `composer card delete --name admin@tutorial-network`

**To Imports a created card into your local wallet**

```
composer card import
```

example : `composer card import --file admin.card --name admin@tutorial-network`

**To Exports and packages a card from your wallet**

```
composer card export
```

example : `composer card export --file exp.card --name exp@sample-network`

**To List all cards currently in your wallet**

```
composer card list
```

example : `composer card list --name admin@tutorial-network`

for more details about network card please refer Hyperledger Composer DOC.